# Find an innocent angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Let D be the perpendicular foot relative to BC in a triangle ABC. Let P be the intersection of the internal angular bisector in C with the side AB, and suppose $C\hat{P}A=45^\circ.$ Find $P\hat{D}B$.

I made a simulation in geogebra, and I found the answer, but I could not find a reason using geometric properties. Thanks in advance.[image: Imagem Geogebra]

Comment: Where $D$ is? Can you send your drawing?

Comment: The problem is, the triangle, and the angle in C, is not fix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $DK$ be a bisector of $\angle ADC$, which interests $PC$ in the point $M$.

Thus, $AM$ is a bisector of $\angle DAC$, which gives 
$$\measuredangle DAM=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle DAC=45^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle ACD.$$
Now, since $\measuredangle ADM=APM=45^{\circ},$ we see that $APDM$ is cyclic.

Thus, $\measuredangle DPM=\measuredangle DAM=45^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle ACD$.

Id est, $$\measuredangle PDB=\measuredangle DPC+\measuredangle PCD=45^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle ACD+\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle ACD=45^{\circ}.$$
Done!

Comment: You did it, thanks a lot! The key is the construction of that bisector DK, then everything follows beautifully, thanks!

Comment: @paimfp Welcome!